# Pydantic con FastAPI devuelve error "model_attributes_type" al enviar formulario

Tags: python

Estoy haciendo una web bastante secilla, estática con FastAPI y Pydantic, el caso es que a la hora de enviar un formulario de contacto, me muestra este error:

```
{
"detail": [
    {
        "type": "model_attributes_type",
        "loc": [
            "body"
        ],
        "msg": "Input should be a valid dictionary or object to extract fields from",
        "input": "nombre=name&email=name%40mail.mx&mensaje=hola+amigo%21",
        "url": "https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.1/v/model_attributes_type"
    }
]
```

}

El formulario en mi HTML:

```
<form id="contactForm" action="/enviar" method="POST">
    <label for="nombre">Nombre:</label>
    <input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre" required><br>

    <label for="email">Correo Electrónico:</label>
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" required><br>

    <label for="mensaje">Mensaje:</label>
    <textarea id="mensaje" name="mensaje" rows="4" required></textarea><br>

    <p></p>
    <button type="submit" data-callback="onSubmit">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

Tengo definido el siguiente script:

```
<script>
    function onSubmit(token) {
        // Envía el formulario
        document.getElementById("contactForm").submit();
    }
</script>
```

El modelo y el método que recoge el formulario en mi main.py:

```
class ContactForm(BaseModel):
    model_config = ConfigDict(from_attributes=True)
    nombre: str
    email: str
    mensaje: str


@app.post("/enviar")
async def submit_contact_form(form: ContactForm):

    # Guardar datos en la base de datos
    db_manager.save_form_data(form)

    # Envía correo electrónico
    subject = "Muchas gracias por enviar sus comentarios"
    recipients = ["cccc@xxxx.info", form.email]
    body = f"Hola,\nA continuación los datos de su mensaje:\nNombre: {form.nombre}\nCorreo Electrónico: {form.email}\nMensaje: {form.mensaje}\n\nMuchas gracias por contactarme."
    
    send_email(subject, recipients, body)

    return {"mensaje": "Formulario de contacto enviado con éxito"}
```

En el log de uvicorn me muestra el siguiente error:
"POST /enviar HTTP/1.1" 422 Unprocessable Entity

Agradecería cualquier ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que tu función (path operation) está esperando recibir la información en formato json, este es el comportamiento por defecto cuando declaras el tipo de un parámetro como un modelo de Pydantic. Para hacer funcionar tu función simplemente define cada uno de los fields en el form en tu función como un parámetro de tipo Form(), así:

```
async def submit_contact_form(nombre: str = Form(), email: str = Form(), mensaje: str = Form()):
```

Naturalmente tienes que hacer el import de Form:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Form
```